# Adding values to a JsonCpp object/nested JsonCpp Json:Value objects

Tags: jsoncpp

I have a JSON object say:

```
Json::Value temp;
temp["example1"] = "first";
```

which will be represented as

```
{
    "example1" : "first"
}
```

Now if I want to add another object into the above object without using the index method, how can I do it? For example:

```
 {
    "example1" : "first",
    "example2" : "second"
 }
```

but avoiding using syntax

```
temp["example2"] = "second";
```

Are there any equivalents to `push_back()` (like in C++ vector/list) in JsonCpp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent to `push_back` in JsonCpp is `append`, but you can use it only on `Json::nullValue` or `Json::arrayValue`.

That makes sense because only one parameter is needed to add an element to an array.
What are you asking is unclear/not possible, because you are trying to create an object, which is like a `std::map` in C++, and two parameters are needed to insert an element here.